# I've been experiencing annoying and unusual ssh behavior. It just hangs..and times out

Tags: ssh, linode

So here is the output from the -vvv flag.

```
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname redacted is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to redacted [redacted] port 22.
```

I'm conecting to a linode VPS. When I switch to proxychains, or try from mobile, It works. But when I do it from my host machine, it hangs, this is before and after I wiped my system and installed a fresh image of linux Ubuntu. I even deleted the VPS and built a new one. Still same issue. But it works in the beginning just fine. But when I ssh on the following day, the hanging begins. Has anyone had this exact same problem before.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a programming question.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com? http://superuser.com?